# Windbg Unable to find module 'Wdf01000.sys'

Tags: driver, wdk, wdf

I have Windbg running and want to check source level debugging of WDF.

If I run the command "!lmi wdf01000.sys", I get the following result:

```
kd> !lmi Wdf01000.sys
Loaded Module Info: [wdf01000.sys] 
wdf01000.sys not found
```

If I look in the symbol cache the wdf01000.pdb is there. I use the latest Windows 10 version with the actual WDK.

I followed the article [new support for source-level debugging of WDF in Windows 10](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windows_hardware_and_driver_developer_blog/2015/06/18/new-support-for-source-level-debugging-of-wdf-code-in-windows-10/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself. I forgot to call `.reload`. 
Then I came into the next problem and this was that the source was not shown. For this read in addition to the above article [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/l---l---set-source-options).

```
[l+, l- (Set Source Options)][1]
```

Yes, the first is the worst. :-)

Comment: I don't no why but if you make .reload the module isn't source indexed. Using .reload /f corrects this.